# How to code a piece-wise linear regression

Tags: python, graph, piecewise

I am very new to coding and I need to plot a graph that has a piece-wise linear regression in python (for coursework). Basically I have five data points and I want individual lines connecting them. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

(In addition to this I would like to know how to code to achieve the probabilities of the in between values such as 24,33 etc)
This is the code I have so far:

```
ages = [20, 30, 35, 40, 45]

probabilities = [1 / 1500, 1 / 800, 1 / 270, 1 / 100, 1 / 50]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

plt.title('Maternal age affecting likelihood of having a Down Syndrome child')

plt.xlabel('$Age$')

plt.ylabel('$Probability$')

plt.scatter(ages, probabilities)
```

Comment: So you are trying to draw straight lines between these points? Or are you trying to fit a curved line over the entire data set, I'm confused...

Comment: Sorry if I didn't word it well, straight lines between the points

Answer (score 0):

You are getting points because you chose `plt.scatter()` which makes a scatter plot. If you'd like a line plot instead just switch to `plt.plot()` such as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ages = [20, 30, 35, 40, 45]
probabilities = [1 / 1500, 1 / 800, 1 / 270, 1 / 100, 1 / 50]

plt.title('Maternal age affecting likelihood of having a Down Syndrome child')
plt.xlabel('$Age$')
plt.ylabel('$Probability$')
plt.plot(ages, probabilities)
plt.show()
```

Yielding:

[image: line plot]

To interpolate based on this data is pretty simple with `numpy`. You just run:

```
import numpy as np

ages = [20, 30, 35, 40, 45]
probabilities = [1 / 1500, 1 / 800, 1 / 270, 1 / 100, 1 / 50]

prob_32 = np.interp(32, ages, probabilities) # change 32 to whatever age you want
print(prob_32)
```

But this will print probability as `.00223` instead of say 1/450 but you could just say `1/prob_32` to get the 450 number!

Comment: That's brilliant- thank you! I would want to use the model from the graph to get the values I believe